# ms access visual basic 2010 report does not order by

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

this one is the screenshot on the visual basic report. as you can see it starts at august then december then february but it i already group by it on the access which is this.
[image]

this is a query in the access im not sure if i did the right thing but i is already ordered by the earliest .

[image]

here is the sql code from the ms access

```
SELECT MonthName(Month([Date_sold])) & ' ' & Year([Date_sold]) AS Month_Sold, Sum(tblSell.Total_Price) AS Total_Earnings, Sum(tblSell.Quantity_Bought) AS Total_Medicine_Sold, tblSell.Generic_name, tblSell.Brand_Name
FROM tblSell
GROUP BY MonthName(Month([Date_sold])) & ' ' & Year([Date_sold]), tblSell.Generic_name, tblSell.Brand_Name, Year([Date_sold]), Month([Date_sold])
ORDER BY Year([Date_sold]), Month([Date_sold]);
```

in short is it doesnt order by on my report on the visual basic it should show february first like the one on ms access but it shows august which is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order by, I believe, gets over written by the reports Order By property in the Data tab, on the property sheet.  Either set it there or make sure it is empty.  Then set the reports properties like this:

```
Me.OrderBy = "[SomeField], [AnotherField]"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

EDIT:
All Microsoft products allow developers access to a development environment using a language called VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).  You can use this language to write programs and macros to enhance products.  Take a look here, although it's a bit old it may still be relevant: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvba/l/aa030803b.htm

For you, you will need to add the code I suggested to the OnLoad event of the report.  To do this:

1. Open **Access**.
2. Open your report in **Design View**.
3. On the left hand side, you should see a **tab** called **Property Sheet**
4. Select the **Event Tab**
5. in the **OnLoad** event, click the "**...**" (ellipsis) button
6. This will bring up the **VBA code**.
7. Add This:

```vb
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.OrderBy = "[SomeField], [AnotherField]"
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: uhm sry im noob on vb where should i set the codes? on the .rdlc or on the form where i put the reportviewer?

Comment: It's been a while since i worked with this but I believe the best place would be the report itself.  Possibly when the report is created.

Comment: im sorry but i still have no idea where to put it.

Comment: I will append my response to describe how to get to the VBA code in access

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is it not sorting (I am having this same problem at work doing some shipment order reports) is because the code is not reading the date. It will list them aplhabetically because it is a text field and not a short date. I just went to the parameters and was able to fix it there.